# Best way to get geo-location in Java

Tags: java, geolocation

What is the best way to get geo-location in Java (freely if possible)?

Update: Not from a GPS device. Basically how Firefox 3.5 / HTML 5 does it

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to retrieve coordinates from a GPS device or find the location based on an IP address or look up coordinates of certain destinations in a database or something else?

Comment: Is this for a desktop application that needs to do it off-line? Or are web services OK to use?

Answer (score 19):

An easy way is with GeoLite (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/). Because it uses a local database no web service calls are needed and it's much faster for geocoding large numbers of IPs.

Here is how:

Add this Maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Download the geolocation data file from http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

Unpack the file into any folder. Then do:

```
LookupService cl = new LookupService("/var/geolite/GeoLiteCity.dat",
                    LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE | LookupService.GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE);

Location location = cl.getLocation("some ip address");
```

The result will be in the Location object in the latitude, longitude, city, region and countryCode properties.

Please take a look at their accuracy estimates to ensure it meets the needs of your project: http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite_city_accuracy .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how Firefox 3.5 (or Google Chrome) gets the geolocation, then please take a look here: [How Google/Firefox Geolocation API works](http://web.archive.org/web/20121122085538/http://my.opera.com/CrazyTerabyte/blog/2009/07/23/how-google-firefox-geolocation-api-works)

Basically, what Firefox 3.5 (as well as Chrome) does is to get the list of nearby Wi-Fi networks and send that list using JSON to a Google webservice, which will then return the approximate coordinates.

By the way, there is no Java involved in this process. To get geolocation from Firefox/Chrome, you just call a few JavaScript methods. (I really hope that you know that Java is different from JavaScript)

Comment: The link added in this answer is dead now

Comment: @SpringLearner: Thanks! I should really put my blog back online. Meanwhile, I updated the link to the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Hey @DenilsonSáMaia I want exactly same solution using java method which takes ip as argument. Can you provide some pointer? If you could be able to provide the javascript implementation, that also will be help.