# Java library to get geo-code from ipaddress

Tags: java, geocoding

My application knows the IP address of the user.
We need to identify the city, state, country of the user and latitude & longitude of the user.

Is there a java library that can do this?

If there is none, what is algorithm or data-source used to convert IP address to geo-graphic location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.maxmind.com/app/developers provides a local database and java classes to calculate the location information from IP address. I did some testing. The results seem to be good.

```
bbc.co.uk: 212.58.241.131 : 51.283295,-0.23330688;Tadworth,N7,United Kingdom,null
home: 76.126.242.196 : 37.369705,-122.0214;Sunnyvale,CA,United States,94086
google.com: 74.125.224.133 : 37.419205,-122.0574;Mountain View,CA,United States,94043
tcs.in: 202.71.129.225 : 28.666702,77.216705;Delhi,07,India,null
ebay.com: 66.135.205.13 : 37.280304,-121.956696;Campbell,CA,United States,95008
etrade.com: 12.153.224.22 : 34.091797,-84.2209;Alpharetta,GA,United States,30005
whitehouse.gov: 72.247.136.110 : 42.362595,-71.0843;Cambridge,MA,United States,02142
```

Here is the link to the junit testcase I used, [GeoLiteCityTest.java](https://github.com/snambi/GeoIP/blob/master/src/test/java/com/maxmind/geoip/GeoLiteCityTest.java)

MaxMind provides java classes, but not jars. So, I have created a maven project that can build the code and generate jars. Here is the GitHub Project https://github.com/snambi/GeoIP

If you need to use this library in your maven project, add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geomind</groupId>
   <artifactId>geoip</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the following repository configuration, under "repositories" in the pom.xml

```
<repository>
   <id>geoip</id>
   <url>http://snambi.github.com/maven/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup: http://www.maxmind.com/app/developers

They provide a Java API (among others).

Comment: (This will only get you lat/long to the city level, though.)

Comment: WOW, upvote for this and how do i bookmark this so i can look at it when I get home? I've been working on a network security package that this would be awesome to go with

Comment: @mnuss thanks for the link. any idea how they decode the ip address to      location?

Comment: I did some tests, it is a good library. I'll post the findings as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple library in Scala that uses [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com) to get a geo-location. This can also be used from Java as long as you include scala-library.jar on the classpath. You'll need an API key from IPInfoDB. You can get output in JSON, raw, or XML format.

The code and some more documentation are on my [Github](https://github.com/bblaine/GeoIp) and there is also a [jar](https://github.com/downloads/bblaine/GeoIp/ipgeomap_2.9.1-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) for download.

Here's a Java snippet that will get the geo information with "city" resolution:

```
GeoIP geoip = new GeoIP("<API Key>");
//Note the $.MODULE$ syntax to refer to the case class in Scala.
System.out.println(geoip.getGeoRaw("<IP Address>", City$.MODULE$));
```

This example outputs `OK;;0.0.0.0;US;UNITED STATES;DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA;WASHINGTON;20001;38.9048;-77.0354;-05:00` which is the raw output which can then be parsed.

Also see this question [Best way to get geo-location in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1415851/390708)

Comment: IPInfoDB is purely a web API. It would be nice if can be done within the application. The previous answer provided a good database. I'll post the details as a separate answer. Thanks for providing another stackoverflow thread. It has good information. It would be good to consolidate everything into one place.