# JAVA locale : two different Country name on same machine

Tags: java, spring-mvc

On my local machine. In my jsp I am using

```
Locale.getDefault();
```

it prints `India` as country name

In spring controller I use

```
public @ResponseBody HashMap searchOffer(Locale locale){
    locale.getDisplayCountry()
}
```

It display 'United State`. Why? two different Country on same machine..

Which one should I use to read the the user's locale?

Comment: `Locale.getDefault()` reports the JVM/System default. `locale` isn't known to us. Where do you get it from?

Comment: i am running this app in my local machine

Comment: Sure, but we don't see how `locale` is instantiated. How do you initialize the variable?

Comment: The default locale for the JVM can be specified (overwritten) using `-Duser.locale` when starting Java. Maybe the startup script for your servlet container specifies such an option.

Comment: I just want to know the country name of the user who is requesting jsp page

Comment: AFAIK this locale is derived from the `Accept-Language` HTTP header. You sure your browser doesn't send "en-US" as the first choice?

Comment: Yah in firebug I can see `Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5` under `Request Headers`

Answer (score 0):

While I have no knowledge of the Spring Framework, the way to figure out a per request `Locale` object without session information is usually by looking at the `Accept-Language` HTTP header. Which isn't a [very good choice](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales.en) because it misleads people to think they'll acquire the user's whereabouts.

As the link above states, you probably want to give the user a way to override your first guess by storing a preference option, looking at the request IP (using a geocoding database like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11298462/785663)) or something else. Where "storing a preference option" is the only thing that requires the notion of a "returning user". Most common choices are storing the `Locale` object in the user's session. You can read about the (spring specific) list of options [in the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver).

To answer the question: the static method `Locale.getDefault()` will report the JVM "fallback" locale, which is usually derived from the system the JVM is running on (or as @a_horse_with_no_name points out, can be overriden with `-Duser.locale`).