# how do i find my geolocation through java (console based code)

Tags: java, api, google-maps, url, geolocation

I want to try to get lat and long of my PC but like other PCs it do not containing any **GPS** device. So is it possible to get the location through **Google Maps**. Though I don't know much more about the **geo coding** Google need an `URL` to find the latitude and longitude of device, could anyone tell me how do i get this thing in console based application, is it possible?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1415851/2115680

Answer (score 0):

Google provides GOOGLE MAPS API.Through this you could get the Lat and Long of ur PC

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

The above link has the documentation for GOOGLE MAPS API

Comment: That link contains API for websites which are related to javascript but i want to track the geolocation of my PC using only java

Answer (score 0):

Try installing android plugin to the IDE you use. Or download the eclipse bundle that comes with android plugin. You can find a tutorial on this youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-n6p6RxSS8 for getting geolocation information.

Comment: i have eclipse but according to you it will the location of mobile device whereas i want to find the location of PC using java