# How do I show items on my website according to the location of the user?

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I made a website in Java and Google App Engine about tuitions. I want to show only the tuitions near that user. So how can I do this?
Link to the website: http://tut-points.appspot.com
If you can see, it is showing all the courses which were added, but I want to show only the courses which are near to the user.

Comment: Java based solution can be found at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415851/best-way-to-get-geo-location-in-java/47125115#47125115

Answer (score 1):

Are you on App Engine Standard? If so you should be receiving these headers giving you the user's general location:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers#app_engine-specific_headers

> X-AppEngine-Country
>
> Country from which the request originated, as an
>   ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. App Engine determines this code from
>   the client's IP address. Note that the country information is not
>   derived from the WHOIS database; it's possible that an IP address with
>   country information in the WHOIS database will not have country
>   information in the X-AppEngine-Country header. Your application should
>   handle the special country code ZZ (unknown country).
>
> X-AppEngine-Region
>
> Name of region from which the request originated.
>   This value only makes sense in the context of the country in X
>   -AppEngine-Country. For example, if the country is "US" and the region is "ca", that "ca" means "California", not Canada. The complete list
>   of valid region values is found in the ISO-3166-2 standard.
>
> X-AppEngine-City
>
> Name of the city from which the request originated.
>   For example, a request from the city of Mountain View might have the
>   header value mountain view. There is no canonical list of valid values
>   for this header.
>
> X-AppEngine-CityLatLong
>
> Latitude and longitude of the
>   city from which the request originated. This string might look like
>   "37.386051,-122.083851" for a request from Mountain View.